# Matlab/Octave floor (678.0) = 677.0?

Tags: matlab, octave, floor

First I seperate integer part and floating part of a floating value with 4 digits (e.g. 5.678)
Next I multiply the floating part by 1000 to get an integer and then put this integer into floor function.

```
x = 5.678
int_part = floor (x)            % result is 5
float_part = x - int_part       % result is 0.678
float_part = float_part * 1000  % result is 678
floor (float_part)              % returns 677 instead of 678
```

What's going on here? How can I tell Matlab/Octave to return the right value?

Thx in advance

Comment: The reason is that `5.678-5==0.678` returns `0`, ie. `false` due to machine-precision arithmetic. Try adding `eps` to your remainder: `float_part=x-int_part+eps`. Some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Comment: Display more digits using `format long g` to see how `5.678` is being stored.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 5.678
int_part = floor (x)            % result is 5
float_part = x - int_part       % result is 0.678
float_part = float_part * 1000  % result is 678
floor (float_part)              % returns 677 instead of 678
format long
disp(float_part)
```

The answer is

```
6.779999999999999e+02
```

So the floor(float_part) is

```
677
```

Comment: Since you added an answer, I suggest suggesting `round` instead of `floor`.